# Problem in the book "Radio Antennas and Propagation"

Tags: antenna, radio, wave, radar

I came across a problem in an electronics textbook by William Gosling, *Radio Antennas and Propagation*.

[image: Question: A space vehicle receiver, operating at 3GHz with an isotropic antenna, will respond on receipt of quanta. A pulsed transmitter with an isotropic antenna on earth has a peak power of 1MW, a pulse repetition frequency of 1000/s and radiates 1kW mean. Assuming that the vehicle cannot integrate energy between successive pulses, what is the maximum range from the earth at which it will receive signals?]

I am an undergraduate and I sent this to my lecturer to help solve but unfortunately, her answer was incorrect. She came up with a maximum range of 283 000 km whilst the book gives a grossly redacted solution of simply 8000 km. I understood her approach to the problem but then she converted quanta into Joules in a way I did not understand.

I have attempted it myself to no avail.

Edit:
My lecturer's attempt
[image: Lecturers attempt at the problem]

My attempt using matlab:
[image: My solution]
[image: My solution continued]

Comment: Well, it would be helpful if you added how she converted quanta to Joule. For me, this seems pretty straightforward: A photon has energy \$E=hf\$, \$h\$ being Planck's constant. 5·10⁵ photons at 3 GHz is very little energy: \$h\approx 7·10^{-34}\,\text{J/Hz}\implies h·3\!·\!10^9\,\text{Hz}\approx 2.1\!·\!10^{-24}\,\text{J}\$. Each TX pulse has 1J (don't know what we'd need the peak power for?), and all you need to do is calculate free space loss.

Comment: yes, you are correct indeed thanks. But there are two sets of antennas a) the space vehicle b) the ground transmitter. Essential, Pr and Pt. Since the energy is tiny, I am guessing the space vehicle has to come closer to earth? E = P*t, therefore the ratio of the two over the radius of the earth and RCS?

Comment: You've seen my solution now you show yours. Doesn't that seem fair @Finance_sav

Comment: If you have attempted it, why not show your solution?

Comment: I would ignore this part of the book and look elsewhere for more modern methods  that use a couple dozen parameters to define path range, e.g.  BW, bit rate SNR modulation type and probability of error , BER for a packet with CRC+FEC. This book uses non-std ways of defining Friis loss and communication range that I would not use.  I relied on better tools back in the 70's during my Aerospace communcation design days.

Comment: _This book uses non-std ways of defining Friis loss and communication range that I would not use. I relied on better tools back in the 70's during my Aerospace communication design days_ honestly might return it quite a shame as it was a promising book. @Andy I should've been more careful with my spelling I'll fetch the guillotine myself ;)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question! I took a different approach that gave me the same answer as the book, so I think I'm on the right track.

The receiver sensitivity is given in terms of energy, which works out to

$$5\cdot 10^5 \cdot h \cdot f = 5\cdot10^5\cdot 6.626\cdot 10^{-34} \text{ J/Hz}\cdot 3\cdot 10^9\text{ Hz} \approx 1\cdot 10^{-18}\text{ J}$$

The transmitter outputs 1 J per pulse, so how much of this energy does the receiver intercept? That requires knowing the [effective aperture of an isotropic antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_aperture#Derivation_of_antenna_aperture_from_thermodynamic_considerations), which is basically \$\lambda^2/4\pi\$. At 3 GHz, that works out to (0.1 m)<sup>2</sup> / 4π.

The transmitter's energy is distributed evenly over a sphere that has a surface area of 4πr<sup>2</sup>, so the surface energy density is

$$\frac{1\text{ J}}{4\pi r^2}$$

The receiver is going to intercept that density multiplied by its aperture, or

$$\frac{(0.1\text{ m})^2}{4\pi}\cdot\frac{1\text{ J}}{4\pi r^2}$$

We just need to find the value of r for which this equals 10<sup>-18</sup> J.
Rearranging terms, we get

$$r^2 \leq \frac{(0.1\text{ m})^2}{(4\pi)^2 10^{-18}}$$

Take the square root of both sides:

$$r \leq \frac{0.1\text{ m}}{4\pi\cdot 10^{-9}}$$

Which works out to approximately 8×10<sup>6</sup> meters, or 8000 km.

Comment: can I share your solution?

Comment: What do you mean? It's on the public Internet. The applicable license is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Comment: This matches the part of the lecturers attempts that @Finance_sav shared - but we're missing the rest zo no way of knowing where she went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Convert quanta to energy, multiply by number of quanta then convert to power**

This is based on \$E = hf\$ where \$f\$ = 3 GHz and \$h\$ is Planck's constant (\$6.6261 × 10^{−34}\$ J*s).

- The energy per quanta is therefore \$1.99 × 10^{-24}\$ joules.
- With \$5 × 10^{+5}\$ quanta that's a total energy of near-enough \$10 × 10^{-19}\$ joules
- For each 1 microsecond pulse\$^1\$, that's a receive power of \$10 × 10^{-13}\$ watts or -120 dBW.

**Find the link/path loss**

Given that the originating pulse power is 1 MW, that's a link/path loss of 180 dB.

**The [Friis transmission equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss#Free-space_path_loss_in_decibels) for isotropic antennas in decibels**

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{Path loss (dB) = 32.45 + } 20log_{10}(f) + 20log_{10}(d)}}$$

Where \$f\$ is in MHz and \$d\$ is in kilometres.

- This means that \$180 = 32.45 + 69.54 + 20 log_{10}(\text{distance})\$
- Therefore, \$78 = 20 log_{10}(\text{distance})\$

Hence, I get distance to be 7,943 km (corrected from earlier).

---

---

\$^1\$ The answer has been edited to fix a brain-fart

- I wrongly calculated the pulse width to be 1 millisecond.
- It's actually 1 μs and this makes all the difference.

A thousand pulses per second means a 1 ms period and, the  peak:average being 1000:1 means a 1 μs pulse width: -

[image]

I guess it does agree with the book (despite the spelling mistakes).

Comment: That's a normal error rate for even english speeking authors ;). But what is the probability of error at -120 dBm

Answer (score 0):

Let's do orders of magnitude to check whose answer is closer to right:

- A photon has energy \$E=hf\$, \$h\$ being Planck's constant. \$h\approx 7·10^{-34}\,\text{J/Hz}\implies h·3\!·\!10^9\,\text{Hz}\approx 2.1\!·\!10^{-24}\,\text{J}\$.
- Each TX pulse has 1J (don't know what we'd need the peak power for? It's 1000 pulses a second, each second we emit 1 kJ, so one pulse has 1 J).
- So, the loss is 1 / (2·10⁻²⁴) = 50·10²²
- Free space path loss is \$\left(\frac{4\pi r f}{c}\right)^2\$, with \$r\$ being the distance between transmitter and receiver.

Solving for \$r\$:

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{4\pi r f}{c}\right)^2 &= 50·10^{22}\\
\frac{4\pi r f}{c} &\approx 7·10^{11}\\
4\pi r f &\approx c· 7·10^{11}\\
r &\approx \frac{c· 7·10^{11}}{4\pi f}\\
&= \frac{3·7·10^{19}}{4·3·3·10^{9}}\text{m}\\
&= \frac{7·10^{10}}{12}\text{m}\\
&\approx 5·10^6\,\text{km}
\end{align}